# Neo4j and product characteristics design

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In my Spring, SDN, Neo4j application I have a groups of products. Each group can define own set of product characteristic and each product of this group can provide an own values to these (0..N) characteristics.

I have a following criteria to this system:

1. Product group must define set(0..N) of characteristics.
2. Each product of this group can provide an own values to these (0..N) characteristics. Type of values  - Numeric, String, Array.. may be spatial data.
3. I need to do sorting and filtering based on product characteristic values in this product group.

Right now I'm looking for a right architectural design of this system.

During investigation I have found [SDN DynamicProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/fieldaccess/DynamicProperties.html) Is it a right thing to implement desired functionality ?

Is it possible to store different types of properties inside of `DynamicPropertiesContainer` ?

How to query(filter, sort) these data later ?

How to create a correlation between defined characteristics of product group and certain product characteristic and its value ?

Comment: Do you have a complete list of which characteristics you can have? Because if you do, you can create one node per characteristic and use relations between your nodes and those characteristic nodes and find easily which node has a certain characteristic.

Comment: No, I don't have such a list. Characteristics can vary from group to group and can be later added/removed also. It was my basic idea to build the characteristic based on the dedicated nodes.. but today I have found DynamicProperties and created this question in order to compare solutions.